# Who should design the nozzle of jet engines on aircraft?

Tags: aircraft-design, jet-engine, engine-design

There is a question in my mind that which company should design the nozzle of jet engine - the aircraft designer or the engine designer?

If you watch this documentary:

[BBC Documentary Rolls Royce How To Build A Jumbo Jet Engine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ho7j8OLV1fk)

You will see that the engine is designed without the nozzle. e.g. You see something just like the following come out from the manufacturer (Trent 700).

[image: image1]

But in fact you will see it on aircraft just like this (Trent 700 on A330).

[image: image2]

Which company designs this duct/nozzle/intake? The aircraft designer (in this case Airbus) or the engine designer (in this case Rolls Royce)?

Comment: Is your question who *does* design the nozzle or who *should* design the nozzle? You asked both in the text but I feel like they are different questions. The later might be opinion based

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect there will be some collaboration between the two (as the nozzle partly determines the performance of the engine), but this is primarily the domain of the aircraft designer. Only he/she knows the (aerodynamic) specifics of the integration of the power plant on the aircraft and is able to make a proper trade-off, for example regarding ground clearance.

A textbook example of that is the integration of the [CFM56](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CFM_International_CFM56) on different aircraft. The Boeing 737 uses [flattened nacelles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_737_Classic#/media/File:Boeing_737-400_Engine.JPG), whereas the nacelles are [circular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CFM_International_CFM56#/media/File:F-GTAR_Air_France_(3698209485).jpg)  on the A320-family. The flattened ones are structurally less efficient, but at aircraft level, it was an easier/better option than increasing the landing gear height. (This problem, by the way, is still haunting the 737-series. A recent innovation featured on the 737 MAX-10 [extends the landing gear using a new lever](https://twitter.com/BoeingAirplanes/status/1035161526188032001/video/1) to prevent the tail from scraping the runway on rotation, another problem of a shorter landing gear.)